# How to position this element in the way indicated using only CSS

Tags: css, positioning

On a responsive page, I need to add a white container as shown on image below: the white container is on top of the slider, but doesn't go further right to the right edge of the "container" class.

It's hard to explain but hopefully with the image and Fiddle below, my problem should be understandable.

How to place this white container so that it remains always in this location, against the right edge of class "container", and against the bottom of the slider, even when reducing window size?

[image]

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Jk2/)

Markup:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="container">
        content
        <br />content
        <br />content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/300/sports/" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/W2Jk2/4/

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I described ! I forgot one thing in my question though: the white container should also stick to the bottom of the slider... Not sure if that is compatible with your solution though. I edited the question.